# SELECT - values to columns in query

Tags: sql

Here's what I want to do.
I have 3 tables: Workplace, Details and Downtime.
So far I select from Workplace table the number of the workplace (and I add it's name from Details table), the date when a notification was made, the shift and the sum of downtime minutes from Downtime table
Now... in Downtime table there is  column with Downtime codes. Every notification has a code and the number of minutes. What I want to do... is too have as many columns as codes... Here's what my query shows me now:

```
|Workplace|Date       |Shift|Downtime|
|1345     |2012-08-28 |1    |100     |
|1346     |2012-08-28 |1    |130     |
|1347     |2012-08-28 |1    |40      |
```

I have the downtime codes in the Downtime table with their reported minutes... and I want it  to be something like:

```
|Workplace|Date       |Shift|Code 1|Code 3|Code 4|Code 6|
|1345     |2012-08-28 |1    |100   |30    |10    | 5    |
|1346     |2012-08-28 |1    |130   |30    |10    | 5    |
|1347     |2012-08-28 |1    |40    |30    |10    | 5    |
```

How can I do something like that?
Thank you!

Comment: How are you calculating the code 3,4 and 6 columns are they constants?

Comment: In Downtime table I have several columns... Workplace, Downtime code, Downtime minutes.... in the first version I used SELECT Workplace, Date, Shift, SUM(Downtime minutes) FROM ... and so on... The name of the Downtime code (Code 1, Code 3, Code 4, Code 6 in the example) is in Downtime table... what I don't know is how can I make   this names become columns in my query (like in the example)

Comment: Is this a question like: how to create a pivot table with SQL? Could you please clarify.

Comment: It does look like he wants to pivot the values in his downtime table, as he has one column for the code, and one column for downtime minutes, and he would like to pivot out the minutes based on the downtime code. He doesn't say which version of SQL he is using, so I gave an ANSI compliant generic version of a pivot using case statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK from your reply I would suggest you have most of you code, so it would end up roughly like this:

```
select 
 tablea.workplace, 
 tablea.date, 
 tablea.shift, 
 sum(downtimemins),
 tableb.code1,
 tableb.code3, 
 tableb.code4, 
 tableb.code6 
from tablea 
left join downtime on 
 tablea.workplace=tableb.workplace and 
 tablea.date=tableb.date and 
 tablea.shift=tableb.shift 
group by tablea.workplace, tablea.date, tablea.shift
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have several columns for each Code... there is just one... but I'll do several left joins ... I don't know how efficient this is... but it will work.

Answer (score 2):

So - you want to break up your downtime into the code that was used for it? 
You should be able to do this using case statements:

SELECT Workplace, Date, Shift, SUM(CASE WHEN Code = Code1 then Downtime ELSE 0) as Code1, SUM(CASE WHEN Code = Code2 then Downtime ELSE 0) as Code2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

my quick answer is you can use cursor and dynamic query.

Cursor example:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Dynamic query example:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/306

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is basically the PIVOT-clause which is introduced in the SQL 2005 standard. AFAIK Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle do support the PIVOT clause. There are third party solutions for postgresql, though I have no clue about other RDBMS.

So depending on the database you're using: you can't or you can (using PIVOT).

Comment: the pivot can be duplicated using case statements in ANSI SQL

Comment: Yes you're right. Just noticed that PIVOT is as static as the CASE variant.